# WebRTC P2P - Update

Tags: html, websocket, p2p, bittorrent, webrtc

When will it be posible to exchange any kind of data via P2P with WebRTC?

I'm thinking about making a P2P bittorrent software, not to stream audio/video.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

There are some JS libraries: [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/) and [BoneValue](https://github.com/theninj4/bonevalue) for P2P data exchanging using WebRTC.

If you want to make a BitTorrent-like JS app for sending files, be aware that there are some already - [BtAppJS](http://btappjs.com), [ShareFest](https://github.com/Peer5/ShareFest), [ShareIt](https://github.com/piranna/ShareIt), [RTC-P2P](http://rohanradio.com/rtc-p2p/), and [P2P-Share](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/p2p-share).

Comment: Wow those are some great links. WebRTC is going to take over and I'm loving it. Right now I have a huge bittorrent service in production relying on embedded Java but you better believe once WebRTC is fully adopted properly we'll be moving to it.

Answer (score 5):

This will available in Chrome using the DataChannel: http://webrtc-demos.appspot.com/html/dc1.html

You can see an overview in this talk from Google I/O: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8C8ouiXHHk&t=24m30s

I have not been able to establish a data connection in Chrome 21 or 22 (Canary), next step is to try compiling for myself.

Answer (score 2):

P2P bittorrent software based on WebRTC already exists. It's called [**WebTorrent**](https://webtorrent.io/) ([source](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent)).

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC that doesn't stream audio/video but arbitrary data is called RTCDataChannel: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel

But you are late - WebTorrent already exists.

WebTorrent client: https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent

WebTorrent tracker implementation: https://github.com/Novage/wt-tracker

Hybrid BitTorrent\WebTorrent tracker: https://github.com/webtorrent/bittorrent-tracker